# ssh-copy-id no identities found ubuntu error

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two machines that were setup exactly the same with the same name and users and everything exactly the same. Each machine has two users with this names userA (**u**serA@**U**serA) and userB (userB@UserA). I've connected both machines using a cable and setup a network wired connection and then `ping` and they both can see each other.
This is how the `etc/hosts` look like in both machines:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   UserA

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.0.1    master
192.168.0.2    slave
```

what I want to do is to change the `UserA` from both machines to make one named `master` and the other called `slave` so that on the master the users will be like this (`userA@master` and `userB@master`) while on the slave they will be (`userA@slave` and `userB@slave`).

The other thing I want to be able to do it is running this command:

```
userB@master:~$ ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub userB@slave
```

but the problem when I run it I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
```

So if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Well, are there any identities to copy. ;) In other words, have you run `ssh-keygen` on `master`?

Comment: Isn't this question about changing the hostname (the part before `ssh-copy-id` comes into play)?

Comment: @fkraiem i think so, as i've followed the steps here http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/ and now trying to follow the steps found here to make a multinode cluster http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/ , but how to check whether the ssh-key is run on the master or not?

Comment: @Jan yes, i want to do this but i don't know how

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question 1

How can I change the hostname?

To change the hostname of a Linux machine, use the `hostname` command. Also read [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname), it has some more relevant information.

If you need to change the hostname as the other machine resolves it, change the `/etc/hosts` file, if you used that.

#### Question 2

> I want to be able to do it is running this command:
>   userB@master:~$ ssh-copy-id [...]

You have to generate ssh keys first, use `ssh-keygen` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen)) for that. For e.g.:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding Question1, could you tell me what changes needed to be done in the hosts file? I already posted it in my question. Regarding question2, is there a way to check if there is an already key generated?

Comment: @shepherd **Please ask your questions separately** so that others with the same problem can benefit. Comments are for asking for clarification, etc...